# Linq request list in dictionnary

Tags: c#, linq

Dictio is a `Dictionary<string, Grouped>`.

Grouped is a class contains a list of Task.

I want to select A task based on 2 params "name" and "computerName".
As return value I want a Task Object (Name + computerName gives 1 Task)

My code :

```
var task = Dictio
  .Select(s => s.Value.Tasks.Where(( z => z.Name == task.Name && 
                                          z.ComputerName == task.ComputerName )));
```

Comment: and what´s the problem? Any exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: It returns me an array whitch contain an array and my task is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = "SomeName";
var computerName = "ComputerName";

var tasks = Dictio.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Tasks) // flatten all tasks to one list
                  .Where(z => z.Name == name && z.ComputerName == computerName )); // query

// tasks will be a list of tasks, if you want only one of them:

var task = tasks.FirstOrDefault();
// task will be the first found task or null if no task matched your query
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added a FirstOrDefault().
The SelectMany is a tool I always forgot.

Comment: You're very much welcome, good luck. Consider accepting my answer if it helped you.